# Android: move button does not work?

Tags: android

I want to add a listener to a button, that change position of this button. I've tried to solve the issue with this snippet but dont work as I expected.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int top = button.getTop();
            button.setTop(top + 40);
        }
    });
```

this code just move the top and not the entire button. Indeed, after the click action, button become height jsut few points and I dont see the label. What's wrong?

If it can help us to better understand my issue, I'll show you other method:

```
private void addButton(String text) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            width,
            lineHeightButton
    );
    layoutParams.leftMargin = leftMargin;
    layoutParams.topMargin = getNewTop(lineHeightButton);

    final Button button = new Button(_mainActivity);
    button.setText(text);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int top = button.getTop();
            button.setTop(top + 40);
        }
    });

    _frameLayout.addView(button);
}
```

---

Fixed:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
            layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    button.getWidth(),
                    button.getHeight()
            );
            layoutParams.leftMargin = leftMargin;
            layoutParams.topMargin = button.getTop() + 40;
            button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in `setTop` method. If you want to rearrange your button position you need :

1) get a current `LayoutParams` of `Button`

2) set values of position what you want.

3) get back to reset of `Layout Params` of `Button`.

Actually you want to move, but you just a set top border of button, not a position.